# C strcmp implementation using subtraction of characters

Tags: c

I saw this implementation of `strcmp` a while back, and I have a question for purely education purposes. Why is it needed to convert the inputs to 16bit integers, do the math and then convert back to 8bit? What is wrong with doing the subtraction in 8bit?

```
int8_t strcmp (const uint8_t* s1, const uint8_t* s2)
{
  while ( *s1 && (*s1 == *s2) )
  {
    s1++; 
    s2++;
  }

  return (int8_t)( (int16_t)*s1 - (int16_t)*s2 );
}
```

Note: the code assumes 16 bit `int` type.

**EDIT:**
It was mentioned that C does conversion to `int` (suppose 32bit) by default. Is that the case even when the code explicitly states to cast to 16bit `int` ?

Comment: That is not standard compliant, do not use it.

Comment: About your **EDIT**, yes it's still the case. Notionally, the values are cast to `int16_t` and then converted to `int` (if `int` is wider than `int16_t`, which it might not be, although it will be at least as wide as `int16_t`).

Comment: Maybe the point is to guarantee non-portability. `int8_t` and `int16_t` do not exist on systems that don't have native hardware types of those sizes.

Comment: What if *s1 is 255 and *s2 is 1? Then `(int16_t)*s1 - (int16_t)*s2` yields 254, and `(int8_t)254` yields an implementation-defined value, probably -2. -2 < 0 even though *s1 > *s2 so this result will be wrong.

Comment: the cast in `(int16_t)*s1 - (int16_t)*s2` is unnecessary because all types less than int must be promoted to int before any arithmetic operations

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The *strcmp(a,b)* function is expected to return

- `<0` if `string a < string b`
- `>0` if `string a > string b`
- `0` if `string a == string b`

The test is actually made on the first char being different in the two strings at the same location (0, the string terminator, works as well).

Here since the function takes two `uint8_t` (unsigned char), the developer was probably worrying about doing a comparison on two unsigned chars would give a number between `0` and `255`, hence a negative value would never be returned. For instance, `118 - 236` would return `-118`, but on 8 bits it would return `138`.

Thus the programmer decided to cast to `int_16`, signed integer (16 bits).

That could have worked, and given the correct negative/positive values (provided that the function returns `int_16` instead of `int_8`).

**<sup>(*edit: comment from @zwol below, the integer promotion is unavoidable, thus this `int16_t` casting is not necessary)</sup>**

However the final `int_8` cast breaks the logic. Since returned values may be from `-255` to `255`, some of these values will see their sign reversed after the cast to `int_8`.

For instance, doing `255 - 0` gives the positive `255` (on 16 bits, all lower 8 bits to 1, MSB to 0) but in the `int_8` world (signed int of 8 bits) this is negative, `-1`, since we only have the last low 8 bits set to binary `11111111`, or decimal `-1`.

---

Definitely not a good programming example. 
That [working function](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-262/ppc/gen/strcmp.c) from Apple is better

```
for ( ; *s1 == *s2; s1++, s2++)
    if (*s1 == '\0')
        return 0;
return ((*(unsigned char *)s1 < *(unsigned char *)s2) ? -1 : +1);
```

(Linux does it in assembly code...)

Comment: infinitely clearer!
However, one last question for educational purposes. When casting from say `int_16` down to `int_8` are the LSB or MSB bits preserved, or is it implementation dependent?

Comment: The result of converting `int16_t` to `int8_t` is implementation-defined. Most implementations simply discard the upper bits.

Comment: With or without the casts to `int16_t`, the actual subtraction will be done on `int`, due to the integer promotions.  `int` is allowed to be the same type as `int16_t`, but it is *not* allowed to be the same type as `int8_t`, so the integer promotions are unavoidable; there is no way (within the standard) to force C to actually do arithmetic on `[u]int8_t` quantities. (Note a difference between `int8_t` and `char` here; on an implementation where `CHAR_BIT >= 16`, `int` and `char` may be the same type; however, such an implementation cannot provide `int8_t` at all!)

Comment: @zwol - when `CHAR_BIT >= 16`, `int` and `char` can have the same underlying representation, but they are still different types. Otherwise overloading would be rather fragile...

Comment: @PeteBecker "Overloading"? C knows not this "overloading" ;-)

Comment: @zwol - whoops, I don't ordinarily read C questions, but got to this one through the back door. <g>

Comment: @PeteBecker Less flippantly, you're right - `int` and `char` would be "assignment compatible" but not "compatible" under the conditions we're imagining, and this would be visible in a small number of ways (e.g. you still couldn't pass a `char*` to a function taking an `int*` argument without an explicit cast).  But what's relevant for this question is the integer promotions, which only care about the relative sizes of the types: `char` arithmetic really wouldn't get promoted to `int` if `sizeof(char)==sizeof(int) [==1]`.

Comment: I'm not sure whether to vote this down or up. The first part of the reasoning is incorrect for the reason zwol gives, but nevertheless it's fairly plausible that the author of the code thinks exactly the same thing in which case it does accurately explain why the code was written that way. And the warning that the code is wrong anyway is pretty important!

Comment: Apple's open source version use C but the real version uses assembly with SSE/AVX so it's much faster

Comment: Answer edited to reflect the insightful comment from @zwol.

Comment: The Apple function looks worse than what the OP had, though... multiple return statements are unnecessary. Also it seems they are abusing unsigned overflow.

Answer (score 9):

Actually, the difference must be done in at least 16 bits¹ for the obvious reason that the range of the result is -255 to 255 and that does not fit in 8 bits. However, sfstewman is correct in noting that it would happen due to implicit integer promotion anyway.

The eventual cast to 8 bits is *incorrect*, because it can overflow as the range still does not fit in 8 bits. And anyway, [`strcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) is indeed supposed to return plain `int`.

---

¹ 9 would suffice, but bits normally come in batches of 8.

Comment: I think the reason the programmer is only concerned with the sign of the result so as long as that is retained its ok

Comment: The operands will always be promoted to `int`, which must hold at least 16-bit values, before the subtraction, which makes the 8-bit nature of the operands irrelevant.  See the integer promotion rules (C11 6.1.1.3p2).

Comment: _pedant mode_: "the difference must be done in at least **9** bits..."

Answer (score 3):

Input data is unsigned 8-bit, so to avoid truncation and effects of overflow/underflow it should be converted to at least 9-bit signed, therefore int16 is used.

Comment: Then they go and ruin the result by returning a `int8_t`!

Answer (score 2):

```
return (int8_t)( (int16_t)*s1 - (int16_t)*s2 );
```

This could mean one of these two options:

- Either the programmer was confused about how implicit type promotions work in C. Both operands will be implicitly converted to `int` no matter the casts to `int16_t`. So if `int`is for example 32 bits, the code is nonsense. Or otherwise if `int` is equivalent to `int16_t` for the specific system - then no conversion at all takes place.
- Or the programmer is well-aware about how type promotions work and is writing code that needs to confirm to a standard that bans implicit type promotions, such as MISRA-C. In that case, and in case `int` is 16 bits on the given system, the code makes perfect sense: it forces an explicit type promotion to dodge warnings from the compiler/static analyser.

I would make a guess that the second option is the most likely, and that this code is indended for a small microcontroller system.

Comment: your second guess is correct. It is intended for MISRA-C

Comment: I'm not sure how such a standard can "ban" implicit type promotions, or does it only apply to certain expressions? (For example, the expression `*s1 == *s2` in the original code also involves implicit type promotions, at least notionally, although such promotions would have no effect for the `==` and `!=` operators in this case.

Comment: @IanAbbott: The intent of the MISRA standard is to require that code not only work under the rules of C, but that it also be written so that it would work the same way in a language with rules that were independent of the size of "int".  Unfortunately, some quirks in the rules of C make it hard to write code whose behavior is int-size independent.  For example, `uint16_t x=65535; x*=x;` will set `x` to 1 on all platforms where `uint16_t` is defined and `int` is either 16 bits or 64 bits, but on some machines where `int` is 32 bits it may negate the laws of time and causality.

Comment: @IanAbbott The MISRA rules regarding when to explicitly cast to avoid type promotion are rather intricate and depends on version of MISRA-C. The type promotion of the operands of `==` should not be dangerous, because the result is an `int` 1 or 0, and not a promoted type.

Comment: @rici If you wish to write your own MISRA-C compliant standard library functions, you'll have to re-define the standard function definitions, since the C std lib itself is not MISRA compliant. Casting to `int8_t` and returning it makes perfect sense in a small microcontroller system.

Comment: @lundin: fortunately, that is not one of my ambitions. Still,  I'm now vaguely curious what conceivable advantage there is to strcmp returning an int8_t rather than an int. If you do want to return an int8_t, then you'll have to restrict its range; the cast as written can overflow and that is surely not safe, MISRA or no.

Comment: @rici The cast can't overflow because there are two characters being compared, assuming they are standard 7 bits wide ASCII. The advantage of using `int8_t` over `int` is that it saves execution speed on small processors and it saves 1 byte of memory on most CPUs. Also it makes the return type and signedness deterministic: you know it returns a 1 byte two's complement signed integer. If you use `int` you don't know a thing about its format: could be anything from 16 to 64 bits and could be any form of weird signedness that the C standard allows. Code using `int` is generally non-portable.

Answer (score 1):

There are certain values that would cause the difference between the two numbers to be different if the `int16_t` weren't there due to overflow. In an `int8_t` your range is  -128 to 127, in  a `uint8_t` your range is 0 to 255, and in a `int16_t` your range would be -32,768 to 32,767.

Casing to an `int8_t` from a `uint8_t` will cause values over 127 to change signs due to overflow so this keeps that from happening, however the output should be an `int16_t` due to if you had a 255 - 0 result, it would be a truncated return.